# Create a batch file that will zip two files with the same name (but different extensions)

Tags: batch-file, zip

I'm very new to programming and I recently started working at a data archive facility. A large part of my job is zipping pdf and AutoCAD files (.dwg) together. My manager has me doing this by hand and there are thousands of files to zip, so I am looking for a more efficient way.

At the moment, I have a folder that contains about 500 files, 250 of them are PDFs and 250 of them are drawings. Each pdf has a matching drawing with the same name and I want to zip them together in pairs. (The zip file should have the same name.)

The naming convention is like this:
1.pdf
1.dwg
2.pdf
2.dwg
...etc.

I want to create something like this:
1.zip (containing 1.pdf and 1.dwg)
2.zip (containing 2.pdf and 2.dwg)

I have done some research already and I understand that many people have written similar programs using batch files. However, I find myself stuck. I do not have permission to download 7zip or anything that doesn't come with Windows 7.

I tried something like this:

```
 @ECHO OFF
PATH=K:\FOD-FDC\TSG\HOLDING\ROTATE\OSU-090344\Vol_4_complete
FOR %F IN (*.dwg) DO 7Z a "%~nF.zip" "%~nF.dwg" "%~nF.pdf"
```

Obviously it's not right for a lot of reasons (most notably I don't have 7-zip) but I am still trying to find a solution.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to double the `%` in a `.Bat`file :

Try like this

```
@ECHO OFF
set $PATH="K:\FOD-FDC\TSG\HOLDING\ROTATE\OSU-090344\Vol_4_complete\"
pushd %$path%
FOR %%F IN (*.dwg) DO 7Z a "%%~nF.zip" "%%~nF.dwg" "%%~nF.pdf"
popd
Echo Done !!!
```